# How to get the most recently created records in Azure Mobile Service for a UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, azure-mobile-services

I have a code where I want to get 50 records at a time from a **Azure Mobile service** in a **Universal App**, but I want them to be **ordered by created date(Most recently added)**.
Note : I don't want to get the 50 records first and them order as this means only these 50 records are sorted but there might be more records which are most recently added.

So would like to know what type of query should I write or do I have to manipulate my javascript for read on the server.

My current code is very simple.

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<SampleTable> currentQuery;
//Initialize The table 'sampleTableOnServer'
currentQuery = sampleTableOnServer.Take(50).Skip(0);
List<SampleTable> result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

This gives me 50 records randomly, So how do I write the query for my condition.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to have a column with a date, e.g. CreatedAt. Then you can in your `sampleTableOnServer` using `System.Linq`, you can then sort the table based on `OrderByDescending` or Ascending, in this function you specify the parameter that it should order by. (ahh sorry this is c# but similar should exist :) )

Comment: There is a default _createdAt field in the table. But I'm not able to sort by this parameter unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a property CreatedAt of type DateTimeOffset to your data model, which is SampleTable in this case. Then, just add an OrderBy clause to your query:

`sampleTableOnServer.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);`

Comment: Is there anyway I could use the default _createdDate property of the table?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you mean the _createdDate property of the underlying SQLite table?  That won't help, because it will differ from client to client.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for info. I thought that could have been used instead of duplicating the column again.